# Standard C cast of va_arg return value warning

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am developing a C program and have been stumped by this warning. I want to retrieve arguments from the list using `va_arg`.

```
args[i] = (int) va_arg(argptr, int);
```

or

```
args[i] = (char) va_arg(argptr, char);
```

the problem that am getting this warning:

`... void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'...`

the same also for char case.
Any explanation for that?

code:

```
void test_function(va_list argptr, int (*callback)(),
                   int ret_typel)
{
  int i ;
  int arg_typel;
  int no_moreb = TRUE;
  void *args[MAX_FUNCTION_ARGS];
  for (i=0; no_moreb; i++) {
    arg_typel = (int)va_arg(argptr, int);
    switch(arg_typel) {
    case F_INT:
      args[i] = (int) va_arg(argptr, int);
      break;
    case F_CHAR:
      args[i] = (char) va_arg(argptr, char);
      break;
    default:
      no_moreb = FALSE;
      i--;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `args[]` is an array of `void *`.  You cannot assign an `int` or `float` to a `void *` (it doesn't make any sense).  You could get round this by casting, but it's not a good idea.

If you want to store different types in the same variable, consider a union:

```
typedef union
{
    char  c;
    int   i;
    float f;
} MyUnion;

MyUnion args[MAX_FUNCTION_ARGS];

args[i].c = va_arg(argptr, char);
args[i].i = va_arg(argptr, int);
args[i].f = va_arg(argptr, float);
```

**UPDATE**
As Jonathan Leffler correctly points out in his answer, `va_arg(argptr, char)` and `va_arg(argptr, float)` should not be used, due to default promotions for variadic functions.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to the answer -- just because I bothered to reformat the code in the question first ;)

Comment: @Lindydancer: answer the question first; then format the question. :D Sometimes it is hard to understand the question without formatting the code first, which leaves you in a quandary...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or, next time I might avoid reformatting the code all together, making harder for others to understand the question... Oh, I can think of all sorts of evil schemes to make it harder for the rest of you... ;)

Answer (score 10):

A point of detail about the use of `va_arg()`.

You cannot use:

```
va_arg(argptr, char);
```

without invoking undefined behaviour (which is **bad**!).  The variable arguments to a varargs function undergo promotions: `float` is passed as `double`, and `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `short`, `unsigned short` undergo promotion to `int` or `unsigned (int)` as required.  Therefore, you can never pull a `char` directly with `va_arg`; you can only specify promoted types.  You would have to write:

```
char c = (char) va_arg(argptr, int);
float f = (float) va_arg(argptr, double);
```

This time, the cast occurs as a result of the assignment; saying it happens with the cast is not strictly necessary, but does no harm (though I probably wouldn't write the cast in my own code).

Answer (score 3):

The array `args` is a array of `void *`. You assign plain integers to it, which is the reason you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're being passed a void pointer and you are casting the pointer as an int or char.  You need to dereference the void pointer and then cast, or cast it as an (int *) or (char *) first.

Comment: That doesn't really help with the OP's problem though.  But the OP needs to show his/her actual code to get actual help.